# how to parse app permissions from play store with simplehtmldom

Tags: php, parsing, google-play, fetch, simple-html-dom

sorry if my English is not so good

i want parse app permissions from google play store with shd

but the permission dialog is a hidden content in html source
[this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u58V3.jpg)

how i can force shd to show hidden content in html source

is there any way to inject click on a link during fetch source?

my code for fetching:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['app_id'])) { 

require_once('shd.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id='.$_REQUEST['app_id'].'&hl=en'); 
$data=array();
```